# How to model two variables with a cumulative exponential relationship?

Tags: r, regression, modeling

Suppose I have a response variable(`y`), which is normally distributed, and `y` is generally changed with `x` in a way like a cumulative exponential distribution, which means `y` may reach a plateau at some turning point of `x`, such like that:

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(y=pexp(x)+runif(length(x),0,0.2),x=1:901)
df<-df[sample(1:300,900,T),]
hist(df$y)
plot(df$x,df$y,xlab="x",ylab="y")
```

[image: y] 
[image: xy]

My question is what's the best way to model this sort data? Spline, polynomial or something others?

Comment: In line 2, are you sure you want `runif()` for your error term? People typically assume the errors are normal (ie, `rnorm`). It's fine for them to be uniform, but it's worth being clear on that.

Comment: The rule was adjusted by the line3.